# Unwanted Space between columns (may be alignment issue ) in a grid template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using bootstrap for the first time in a project.

So Long story short , Using a grid template with lot of columns(has many controls inside it) of various heights.

At the end, I find space between some columns because they are of different heights. I cant reduce the height or increase it (Last row columns I can increase and decrease the height). Is there a way to remove the space with the current height of columns ?

I've attached an example of the problem in **Jsbin**, will get an clear idea of the issue.

[**Jsbin Link HERE**](http://jsbin.com/buxavosivo/1/)

Edit:

Check this for more understanding

[image]

Comment: missing closing quotes at style="height:133px; please fix that first

Comment: Your are implementing fixed height which is not equal, is that your requirement?

Comment: yes exactly, last row columns can have dynamic space.In the page which I'm working I got a overall difference of 30px(ignoring the space) between the sum of total columns in the right to the sum of all columns in the left.

Comment: Try this approach > http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/12/working-with-variable-height-css-floats.html

Comment: didn't get the desired result yet, will give a some more try and get back to you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77315/discussion-between-binny-and-sunil-kumar).